# Best database (SQL\NoSQL) for storing file hashes and corresponding description

Tags: database, sql, database-performance, nosql

I am working on a system that store file hashes and a corresponding description

basically, the structure is very simple just 1 table, HASH (key)  and  File Description.

**For example:**

8F28067D10C64952F79542BF1EE349CB  **|**  Windows XP beckgrounf picture

The hash, of course, is also the unique key.

Assuming that this table is going to be huge and that search from the DB should be as quick as possible (by the hash at least)

What will be the best database to use in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the hash key is fixed or small sized, and the description don't go over certain limits beyond ordinary text, any relational or noSQL database with adequate indexing will do. The search speed is in how it's indexed.

Since it's just a 2-column table, most databases can handle it up to their limit on table size (number of rows in this case.)

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was thinking as well, any recommendations for noSQL DB ? I was thinking about using MongoDB for that